# make javascript links openable in a new tab

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have links that are present as `<div>` images with click events getting passed to javascript.

Javascript opens the links by using `location.href = link;`

When I middle click the links they don't open in a new tab though.  How can i make them new tab compatible?

Comment: "<div> images with click events getting passed to javascript" Does this mean that you don't have any `a` elements involved? Would this not be easier?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should turn them into real hyperlinks:

```
<a href="page.html"><img alt="placeholder"></a>
```

Comment: I would add a `target="_blank"` too. I'm not sure if they're still used these days, but they seem to get the job done!

Comment: @Blender That would always open the link in a new window, but it should only do that if the user wants it to. Different browsers have different ways for users to say, "open this link in a new window". For example I do it in Opera using a mouse gesture. Since it is different in different browsers, you need to tell the different browsers that it is a link - ie, use a real anchor tag, instead of faking it with JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Simply don't use JavaScript for links. `location.href` will change the url of the *current* document (window/tab).

Better set the `href` attribute per JavaScript, if you really need to use JS. Using `href` will also be a lot better for accessibility.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `window.open(url)` but it may considered as a popup

```
$('#divid').mousedown(function(e){if (e.which==2) window.open("url_here")});
```

e.which specifies which button was clicked 1 for left 2 for middle and 3 for right!